# Docker : How to add variable to ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When adding a variable to docker `ENTRYPOINT`, the docker build is successful. But when running the docker image I get the below error

```
$> sudo docker run f7edbecba608 .

   .: 1: .: [/usr/lib/dart/bin,: not found
```

However, when variable is not placed in the dockerfile, able to build and run image successfuly.

What is the difference with and without the variable in `ENTRYPOINT`.

Below is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM google/dart

WORKDIR /sample_dir

ADD . /sample_dir

WORKDIR /sample_dir/project

RUN pub get

ARG REDIS_HOST

ENV MY_ENV = $REDIS_HOST

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/lib/dart/bin", "./bin/main.dart", $REDIS_HOST]
```

Command used to build image:

```
sudo docker build --build-arg "REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1"
```

Please let me know if anyother details are required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check if `/usr/lib/dart/bin` actually exist (logging into container)?

Answer (score 0):

The path here for `dart` is the issue. The correct path should be `/usr/bin/dart` - [official ref.](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/google/dart)

You can update the `ENTRYPOINT` to the following:

```
FROM google/dart

WORKDIR /sample_dir

ADD . /sample_dir

WORKDIR /sample_dir/project

RUN pub get

ARG REDIS_HOST

ENV MY_ENV = $REDIS_HOST

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dart", "./bin/main.dart", $REDIS_HOST]
```

Assuming your `main.dart` exist inside `/sample_dir/project/bin/main.dart` based on the your `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set variables during create container or service

```
docker run -e REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

and use it

```
Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;
print(envVars['REDIS_HOST']);
```

or you can define hostname

```
docker run --add-host redis_host=127.0.0.1
```

and you can test `ping redis_host`

Answer (score 0):

The `ENTRYPOINT` must be either a valid JSON array, or it is interpreted as a string.  In your case the variable `$REDIS_HOST` isn't a quoted JSON string, so this gets interpreted as the shell form, and in effect you get

```
ENTRYPOINT sh -c '["/usr/bin/dart", "./bin/main.dart", $REDIS_HOST]'
```

which directly leads to the error you're getting (the first word of that command after handling the double quotes is `[/usr/bin/dart,` and that's not a valid command).

If you need to include things like environment variable expansion, you have to use the shell form of these commands and not the JSON-array form.

```
CMD /usr/bin/dart ./bin/main.dart $REDIS_HOST
```

As @GigaKokaia suggests in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61559954/10008173) you probably want this variable to be a run-time environment variable and not a build-time argument (you don't want to rebuild the image every time you deploy into a different environment; cluster and cloud setups would have different host names) but with this form the `$REDIS_HOST` wouldn't be evaluated until after `docker run -e` environment variable settings are processed.  You could also have your application directly look for the `$REDIS_HOST` environment variable rather than passing it as a parameter.